# How to include and link Sqlite database file in Setup Project

Tags: c#, sqlite, setup-project

I have developed WPF desktop application with C#, Sqlite and Entity Framework. Now the development has been finished and try to create Setup Project.

But I don't know how to include Sqlite database file (myDb.sqlite) in my installation folder and how my ConnectionString in my App.Config should be modified to link to this (myDb.sqlite) in the installation folder?

I use the following extension to create Setup project. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9﻿